# file_get_contents() from external sources

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fread

Today I uploaded a file to my server. Within that file I had `echo file_get_contents('/anotherPage.php');` I was presuming that the method would only get the html of the document but the method not only returned my html. But my php source code as well!

If someone was to use this method on an external server to mine would my source code be visible?

How would I prevent someone viewing my php source code using the following methods: `file_get_contents()`,`fread()`,`file_open()` and other similar methods.

I don't think I have access to the file `php.ini`. So I can't disable the methods can I? 
Anyway I'm not even sure the source code is visible on external servers :S

Comment: To get HTML you need to pass URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code would normally not be visible.

`file_get_contents` in this case was reading the file locally. if you want to only get the HMTL, use a full URL.

Comment: Thank god for that I was really panicking! lol Thanks for a speedy answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No, the source isn't visible externally using **any** method.

You can see the source locally because the function retrieves the contents of a *file*, it doesn't execute the file though.